# SQL - Access - VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access

I’ve to sort a access table to get data between two dates, for example : between the 1st Jan to 31st Jan.

```
SellingID1  iTemID  1   ItemInTime11/01/2011 01:05:00   ItemOutTime11/01/2011 02:05:00
SellingID2   iTemID 1   ItemInTime11/01/2011 02:05:00   ItemOutTime11/01/2011 02:15:00
SellingID3   iTemID 1   ItemInTime11/01/2011 02:05:00   ItemOutTime11/01/2011 03:45:00
SellingID4   iTemID 2   ItemInTime15/01/2011 02:05:00   ItemOutTime15/01/2011 03:05:00
SellingID5   iTemID 2   ItemInTime15/01/2011 02:05:00   ItemOutTime15/01/2011 03:15:00
```

I’ve multiple records within this dates but I need to group them by a ItemID, there could be more than 3 records with the same itemID but I need the minimum time and maximum time among those records and get the output with just one occurrence of the ItemID but time should be calculated in a separate query.

```
1   iTemID 1    ItemInTime 11/01/2011 01:05:00  ItemOutTime 11/01/2011 02:05:00
2   iTemID 1    ItemInTime 11/01/2011 02:05:00  ItemOutTime 11/01/2011 02:15:00
3   iTemID 1    ItemInTime 11/01/2011 02:05:00  ItemOutTime 11/01/2011 03:45:00
```

the above three data should be consolidated into one as below.

```
iTemID 1    ItemInTime 11/01/2011 01:05:00  ItemOutTime 11/01/2011 03:45:00
```

Any guidance would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT ItemID, MIN(ItemInTime) ItemInTime, MAX(ItemOutTime) ItemOutTime
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY ItemID;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9236c/5)** demo

---

> *after finding the min max values in the run time is there a way i can find out the difference between these maxtime and mintime... for each ITEM ?*

Use [`DATEDIFF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx) function for that

```sql
SELECT ItemID, MIN(ItemInTime) ItemInTime, MAX(ItemOutTime) ItemOutTime,
       DATEDIFF("s", MIN(ItemInTime), MAX(ItemOutTime)) DiffInSec
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY ItemID;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20458/2)** demo

Comment: thanks for your response. it worked. But i had a follow up question... after finding the min max values in the run time is there a way i can find out the difference between these maxtime and mintime... for each ITEM ? ... 
really appreciate your efforts... Thanks.